# How to fix toDataURL returning empty string

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, getimagedata

I am trying to turn a simple drawing on a canvas to a base64 url but when I call toDataURL I get an empty string!

The code is below:

```js
var canvas, context, canvasImage;
var cursorPosition = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
};
var mouse;
var color = "rgb(0, 123, 255)";
var size = 10;

function throttle(ms, fn) {
  var lastCallTime;
  return function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (!lastCallTime || now - lastCallTime > ms) {
      lastCallTime = now;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}

function drawCircle(event) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(cursorPosition.x, cursorPosition.y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.closePath();
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
  canvasImage = context.getImageData(
    0,
    0,
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight
  );
  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
}
window.onload = function() {
  socket.emit("ai");
  load("left");
  canvas = document.getElementById("number");
  canvas.width = 140;
  canvas.height = 140;
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  window.onmousedown = function() {
    mouse = "down";
    console.log("hi");
  };
  window.onmouseup = function() {
    mouse = "";
  };
  window.onmousemove = throttle(0.00000000001, function(evt) {
    if (mouse == "down") {
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), // abs. size of element
        scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width, // relationship bitmap vs. element for X
        scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height; // relationship bitmap vs. element for Y

      cursorPosition = {
        x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX, // scale mouse coordinates after they have
        y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY // been adjusted to be relative to element
      };

      drawCircle(event);
    }
  });

  window.ontouchmove = throttle(10, function(event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), // abs. size of element
      scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width, // relationship bitmap vs. element for X
      scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height; // relationship bitmap vs. element for Y

    cursorPosition = {
      x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX, // scale mouse coordinates after they have
      y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY // been adjusted to be relative to element
    };
    console.log(cursorPosition);
    drawCircle(event);
  });
};
```

I am able to draw on the canvas but when I call it in the console or in the code I get and empty string like this: ""

Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried a lot of things online but nothing helps.